# change ip address to domain name without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been surfing for hours and I have not seen an answer that properly resolves my problem.

I have two pages in two different servers. They have to stay that way. One server has a domain name "domain.com" that show one web and it has a button with a link to the other server with the page `ip:port/directory/page.php`.

What i need is that, in the second server, even if it's coming from the first server or by direct access,the page always shows in the URL bar as `domain.com/page.php`, not `ip:port/directory/page.php`.

I've tried with virtualhost in the first server's `httpd-vhost.conf`archive, and changing the `.htaccess` file in `ip:port/directory/` with `RewriteRule`, but nothing properly works.

Thanks for the advice and sorry for my English.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like asking that an app hosted at `http://bogus-cracker-site.example.com/` shows up as `https://www.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking` in the browser location bar. I hope it cannot be done.

Comment: By "it has to stay that way", I presume script execution has to remain on the relevant servers, but have you considered proxying the result from the second server via the server with the domain name? It would require some reconfiguration on the first server, avoiding the situation that @ÁlvaroG.Vicario worries about.

Comment: I think you have more chances to get an answer if you post the question to [su] or [sf]. I have 2 or 3 (possible) solutions in mind and they require changing the configuration of DNS, Apache or other system services.

Comment: stwalkerster: You are talking about Virtualhost configuration? I tried it but with no results, but perhaps I made it wrong.

@axiac: I will see in Server Fault, thanks ;)

Comment: No, @stwalkerster is not talking about virtual hosts. He is talking about Apache on the first server working as a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse) for the other server.

Comment: @GJM - virtual hosts are the complete opposite of what you want to do; they allow you to have multiple websites hosted on multiple domains/IP addresses on a *single server*. You want different parts of the same website hosted on different servers if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved using proxypass and proxyreverse in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass /first_server_folder/ http://ip:port/second_server_folder/
ProxyPassReverse /first_server_folder/ http://ip:port/second_server_folder/

<Location /first_server_folder/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```